# Blue border around video file in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I would like to ask you for a help.
I am using Word press 4.2.2 and inserting videos on my pages. But when i click on it it makes blue border around it.

I tried to change theme style.css, bootstrap.css and even wp-mediaelements.css where i tried border: none and border:0px option. Nothing works.

in IE it is all right, but FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera are still showing that border.

Can somebody make suggestions how to fix this?

Thanks all for help.

Comment: I would suggest showing us some code

Comment: What is your HTML? For which element(s) you tried to set `border: 0;`?

Comment: This could also be an outline, which is a help for people without a mouse on their device (pressing tab shows those outlines. Even the textarea I'm currently typing in has one)

Comment: Adding to @DouwedeHaan, the outline is usually applied to `:focus`. You can set color for that (outline and outline-color respectively).

Comment: I am trying to change setting out of the theme. Because on my web i am using wordpress videos as i posted. So am trying to change wp-includes/js/mediaelements/wp-mediaelements.css here:



.wp-video {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
    outline: none !important;
    border: 0px !important;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was solved by

```
*:focus{
   background: none;
   border: 0px;
   outline: none;
}
```

When I used this, the blue border dissapeared. More info about Focus: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 2):

set `outline` to none in your CSS.

```
#video {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to this on style.css file on that particular class :

```
border: none !important ;
```

**OR**

```
border: 0px !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it on:
/wp-includes/css/**media-views.min.css**

```
.mejs-container:focus {
    outline:1px solid #5b9dd9;
    box-shadow:0 0 2px 1px rgba(30, 140, 190, .8)
}
```